# Error: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback

Tags: plugins, errors

I have issue after upgrading my wordpress to 3.6 see below for errors which displays on wordpress admin panel not on front of website.

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function ‘regis_options’ not found or invalid function name in wp-includes/plugin.php on line 406
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information – headers already sent by (output started at wp-includes/plugin.php:406) in wp-includes/option.php on line 571
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information – headers already sent by (output started at wp-includes/plugin.php:406) in wp-includes/option.php on line 572

Comment: This error can also bubble from a badly formed call to [wp_register_widget_control](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_widget_control/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Somewhere in your theme or plugins is a line like this:

```
add_filter( 'something', 'regis_options' );
```

Could also be `add_action()`. Find that piece of code and remove or fix it.

The other errors are a result of the first one. The printed error message causes output and hence HTTP headers, so PHP/WP cannot send other headers anymore. They will go away when you fix the first error.

Comment: Got the issue the "WP Content Copy Protection" plugin is not compatible with wordpress 3.6 that i have disabled that plugin and THAT WORKS...

Answer (score 11):

```
Warning: call_user_func_array()
```

It is usually caused by a **filter** or an **action** not properly declared.

```
add_filter ( 'action_tag' , array( $this , 'my_callback' ) , 30 );
```

The priority must be outside the callback array parameter. this fixed my issue.

Comment: Bless you! This is exactly my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hi try this solution :

Add this in functions.php:

```
function regis_options($args) {
   return $args;
}
```

Also add this in your class-wp-hook.php:

```
public function regis_options($args) {
echo '<pre>' . var_export($args, true) . '</pre>';
echo '<pre>' . var_dump(debug_backtrace()) . '</pre>';
return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had put a space at the end on my call back string  on calling the filter

```
add_filter( 'something', 'regis_options ' );
```

Instead of

```
add_filter( 'something', 'regis_options');
```

Answer (score 0):

This error will also happen when you call for a function that does not exist.
to solve it
you need to define the 'regis_options' function
try something like

```
function regis_options(){ 
echo 'test';
}
```